# Squid Cache items behind Basic Authentication

Tags: squid

I am using squid as a proxy to cache libraries and various other dependencies, some of which are on servers that require Basic Authentication.

Squid works fine and I can download all the dependencies with it, however I have noticed that it doesn't seem to cache the files that require Authentication. I have tried setting various `refresh_pattern` options, such as `override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private` and so on.

I also tried `ignore-auth` but it is no longer supported and didn't help either.

My Squid itself has no authentication, it is used only by me.

How do I force it to cache these files?

Comment: you did not show the configuration nor did you tell how and for what you are using it

Answer (score 0):

`ignore-auth` is still available in Squid 3.5, so you can fall back to there.
Otherwise, you're out of luck. (I just bumped into the same problem)